# Rounded edges for Android ListView not showing

Tags: android, android-listview, xml-drawable

I need rounded edges for my ListView. I have used drawable/listview_rectangle.xml(shown below) to specify its rounded edges. But it is not working in the device. In Android Studio it shows rounded edges, but in device there are no round edges. Need help in figuring out the exact issue.

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/listview_rectangle"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="6dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/business_main_image"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+ ₹ 2500"
    android:id="@+id/totalAmount"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/business_image"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/business_main_image"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-----------------------------ADDED-----------------------------"
    android:id="@+id/sideTextTop"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/business_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="----------------------------SUCCESS----------------------------"
    android:id="@+id/sideTextBottom"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/business_main_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="23rd August 2015"
    android:id="@+id/paymentDate"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YOU"
    android:id="@+id/profileTextView"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/paymentDate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/business_main_image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/business_main_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WALLET"
    android:id="@+id/paymentReceiver"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/paymentDate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/business_image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/business_image"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

listview_rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid
    android:color="#93BFB6" >
</solid>


<corners
    android:radius="1dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" >
</corners>

</shape>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it on a button? Just to see what happens.
Also check your theme setting in Studio, and the preview API level (this may affect the rendering too)